# ngModel errors.pattern property is always true in Angular template

Tags: angular, html, attributes, angular-ngmodel

Basically I am  trying to check if the user inputs 3 or more characters inside the `Name` field. If so, no error is to be displayed. Otherwise, an error message is displayed to inform the user that s/he has to enter 3 or more characters for the name. However, even when I type more than 3 characters, I still get the error message.

Here is my template's code for Name

```
 <label for="studentName">Name</label>
  <input
    id="studentName"
    name="thename"
    type="text"
    [(ngModel)]="firstStudent.name"
    #varFirst="ngModel"
    required
    pattern=".{3,}"
  />
  <div *ngIf="varFirst.touched && varFirst.errors.required">
    Please enter your name
  </div>

  <div
    *ngIf="
      varFirst.touched && varFirst.errors.pattern && !varFirst.errors.required
    "
  >
    Name should be more than 3 characters.
  </div>
```

Comment: What if you will use safe navigation operator `varFirst.errors?.required`?

Comment: @yurzui I am getting the following error in the console `TypeError: Cannot read property 'required' of null`

Comment: That's because you don't use `?.` operator

Comment: @yurzui i added the `?.`  operator, and i got this error.

Comment: Did you add it in three places? `varFirst.errors?.required` and `varFirst.touched && varFirst.errors?.pattern && !varFirst.errors?.required`

Comment: @yurzui i did not. Now i did an it worked, thanks. Can you please tell me why I need that operator?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188151/discussion-between-marwa-and-yurzui).

Comment: The reason you need this is because there is a cases when your control doesn't have any errors and `varFirst.errors === null` reflects this. When Angular checks your template it executes all your bindings and you're getting runtime error

Comment: Are you open to using the Reactive forms Approch?

Answer (score 2):

If you're open to using the Reactive Forms approach, here's what you can do:

Just create a `FormControl` on your Component Class with `required` and `minlength` validators. And then simply bind it to the view.

This is how it would look like in code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  varFirst: FormControl;
  firstStudent = {
    name: 'John Doe'
  };

  ngOnInit() {
    this.varFirst = new FormControl(this.firstStudent.name, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]);
  }

}
```

And in the Template:

```
<label for="studentName">Name</label>
<input type="text" [formControl]="varFirst"/>

<div *ngIf="varFirst.touched && varFirst.errors">
  <p *ngIf="varFirst.errors.required">Please enter your name</p>
  <p *ngIf="varFirst.errors.minlength">Name should be more than 3 characters.</p>
</div>
```

**PS:** Don't forget to add the `ReactiveFormsModule` to the `imports` array of your `@NgModule`.

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-control-validation-using-reactive-forms?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) for your ref.